# Images not displaying on website? But do on handheld device

Tags: android, ios, wordpress, image, web

NOTE:
Please see: http://elitehitsquad.co.uk/carbon.png

This is where it will show the carbon for a split second then disappear resulting in black! Hopefully the screenshot on the left doesn't show the carbon for you guys!

I had to take a screenshot very quickly for the carbon to show, so the second screenshot has some transparency.

I have also labelled which is black and which is carbon from my screen (incase the carbon shows for you guys)

---

I'm building a website and it's been going fine, had no problems whatsoever, however, randomly after refreshing the page, the background images (which are carbon patterns) are no longer displayed?

The images do display however, on my tablet device and iPhone 5.. which is weird.

I took a screenshot of the website on my phone and emailed it to myself, and even windows doesn't pick up the background when viewed with Microsoft's picture viewer, the carbon displays for about 0.5 seconds, then disappears resulting in a black background..

I have tried loading old code from a backup, still nothing. Chrome, Firefox and IE all do this, and yes, i've also cleared temporary files / temporary internet files and the cache/cookies/site data.

Since im not fussed if you see this part of the site, go ahead to: http://elitehitsquad.co.uk/wp/ and take a look, their is a carbon background for body, a carbon background (slightly different) for the nav bar, and the content is in a black box.. Yet on my computer screen it's just all showing black? But on my handheld devices, it's showing normally...

Anybody know of any reason?

By the way, im using a Lenovo Ideapad Z585 with AMD A10 -4600M APU with AMD Radeon HD 7660G + 7600M Dual Graphics.

Also should note if I change the background to a any solid coloured image, it works fine...

Thanks,
Blake.

Comment: Nope, the background is fine, does not disappear, tested with Opera 12 and Chrome 32

Comment: I know that, it's weird how it's not displaying on my laptop though? Any suggestions for that? I can't seem to find a setting within windows to not display carbon images! hahah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably incomplete monitor calibration issue.

Check your Windows display settings, called `Color management` (if you are on this platform) inside your `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution\Advanced settings`.

There is an color management wizard who will lead you trough the process of calibrating your monitor.

Comment: Just done that before you commented, worked! - Wonder how it changed? - Thank you though!

Comment: Well, the Windows has a nasty habit to change from time to time (with no obvious reason) those settings, it happens to me also.

Comment: It was very weird and puzzled me! - I think i've calibrated it slightly lighter though, i'm just gonna try delete the ICC profiles created and see if that will put it back to "factory calibration"

Comment: Just to let everybody know, I have a touch pad right below my laptop screen, and above the keyboard, with a moon icon which adjusts the brightness of my screen, seems I had nudged this and it dimmed it so therefore darker carbon backgrounds would not show. Problem rectified and finally found out what it was!